# how to use Javascript onKeyDown to control gallery - right and left arrows

Tags: javascript

Please look at [steven.tlvweb.com](http://steven.tlvweb.com)

I want to implement it so the left and right keyboard arrows control the flow.

Currently the scroll wheel works and is set up in the constructor as follows:

```
/*  ImageFlow Constructor */    

    /* add mouse wheel events ==== */
    if (window.addEventListener)
        this.oc.addEventListener('DOMMouseScroll', function(e) {
            if (e.preventDefault) e.preventDefault();
            this.parent.scroll(-e.detail);
            return false;
        }, false);

    this.oc.onmousewheel = function () {
        this.parent.scroll(event.wheelDelta);
        return false;
    }
```

And in the imageflow.prototype further down the code is:

```
    /* ==== mousewheel scrolling ==== */
    scroll : function (sc) {
        if (sc < 0) {
            if (this.view < this.NF - 1) this.calc(1);
        } else {
            if (this.view > 0) this.calc(-1);
        }
    },
```

So, I wrote some code for the constructor:

```
this.oc.onkeydown=function(){
        this.parent.keypress(event.keyCode);
        return false;
    }
```

and in the imageflow.prototype I included:

```
    /* ==== arrow keys ==== */
    keypress : function(kp) {   
        switch (kp) {

        case 39:                        //right Key
        if (this.view < this.NF - 1) {  //if not at far right of gallery
                    this.calc(1);       //move gallery left
        break;
                    }

                    case 37:            //left Key
        if (this.view > 0) {            //if not at far left of gallery
                    this.calc(-1);      //move gallery left
        break; 
                    } 

        }
    },
```

NB Actually there is currently code in the imageflow constructor but it doesn't work (removing it all together even has no effect):

```
    /* ==== right arrow ==== */
    this.arR.onclick = this.arR.ondblclick = function () {
        if (this.parent.view < this.parent.NF - 1)
            this.parent.calc(1);
    }
    /* ==== Left arrow ==== */
    this.arL.onclick = this.arL.ondblclick = function () {
        if (this.parent.view > 0)
            this.parent.calc(-1);
    }
```

I reckon I am missing something relatively fundamental.

Comment: It would be helpful if you created and linked to a http://jsfiddle.net/ with your code. This way we can begin debugging for you right away without a lot of initial work on our part to set it up.

Comment: Jason - I've never used that before - I am a bit of a JavaScript novice! I have put the code here - http://jsfiddle.net/7DTSQ/2 is that what you needed? I didn't know where to put the php code!

Comment: Instead of PHP, you could place the rendered HTML which is the end result of your PHP. In other words, you can open up the page with "View Source" and paste it in.

Comment: Thanks Jason! Ok try http://jsfiddle.net/7DTSQ/8/

What else am I missing to get the preview loading - some CSS???

Comment: Is there any way you can trim your code (html/javascript) down to just the elements and functions in question? Or even some sample code that illustrates what you are trying to accomplish? If not, is there a link to the site in question that is mostly functional? Also, what is your specific question. It is a bit vague.

Comment: steven.tlvweb.com is functional...

I would like to be able to use the left and right keyboard keys to shift the gallery display on the homepage right and left - at the moment only the scroll wheel performs this task.

Comment: If you click on the logo at the top left of the fiddle preview the gallery functions... in the http source <script type='text/javascript' src='steven.tlvweb.com/wp-content/themes/core/js/…; is the file that s relevent and I have copied into the java window below

Comment: OK, I think I've got it....

Comment: Jason, please see the answer I just posted - almost there!!!

Answer (score 0):

I've created a more simple example for you in JSFiddle.

http://jsfiddle.net/nLaGz/

Basically, it looks like you are trying to attach your keyboard events to the this.oc object, which basically represents your `<div id="imageFlow">` element.

The problem is, that `<div>` elements are not input elements, so they don't play nicely with keyboard events since they never really gain "focus" like a form input would.

Luckily, the window.document object is a good place to attach your keyboard events since it will listen no matter what dom element has focus.

try changing your line:

```
this.oc.onkeydown
```

to

```
window.document.onkeydown
```

Comment: Hi Jason I just tried to change the line as suggested but it still does not function at all.

I loaded your JSfiddle and I also can't get it to do anything - tried hitting run but nothing happens.

Maybe I need an event listener?

Comment: http://jsfiddle.net/7DTSQ/14/ under http://jsfiddle.net/7DTSQ/14/ ... doesn't work with either this.oc or window.document

Comment: ahhh I discovered if you add /show to the jsfiddle url your example works! off to bed - thanks for all your efforts and help so far Jason!!!

Answer (score 0):

OK so thanks to Jason I am getting somewhere! Have a look at steven.tlvweb.com to see that the left and right arrow keys are now functioning.

I am just now having a problem with the line

this.parent.scroll(120);

Basically scroll is setup in the prototype to take an integer and move left or right depending on if it positive or negative. I am just not calling it correctly it seems.

this.parent.scroll(event.wheelDelta);

is correct coding for the constructor but within window.document.onkeydown=function() it does not work.

```
function ImageFlow(oCont, xmlfile, horizon, size, zoom, border, start, interval) {

/* === handle mouse scroll wheel === */
this.oc.onmousewheel = function () {
this.parent.scroll(event.wheelDelta);
return false;
    }


/* ==== add keydown events ==== */  
    window.document.onkeydown=function(){
    switch (event.keyCode) {

    case 39:  //right Key
        alert('keyRight'); //move gallery right
        this.parent.scroll(120);

        break;

    case 37: //left Key

        alert('keyleft'); //move gallery left   
        this.parent.scroll(-120);
        break;

    }

    return false;
    }
}

ImageFlow.prototype = {

    scroll : function (sc) {

        alert('here');

        if (sc < 0) {
            if (this.view < this.NF - 1) this.calc(1);
        } else {
            if (this.view > 0) this.calc(-1);
        }
    },

}
```

Comment: so basically just need to know how to call the scroll function - have tried many things but with no luck!